# Cursor doesn't hide while taking a screenshot

Tags: c#, cursor, screenshot

Simple question. I want to take a screenshot of a part of my screen without the mouse pointer in it. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Cursor.Hide();
   gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(//...);
   Cursor.Show();
}
```

The code above was on a button_click event. I transferred the code in a timer_tick event except from the Cursor.Hide() and made the timer's interval 1000. The timer starts when the button is clicked.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Hide();
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(//...);
    Cursor.Show();
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

It works this way but I have to wait 1 sec. When I reduce the interval to 100 the pointer is visible on the image.
I can only assume that the hide method is slower than the CopyFromScreen method...
Is there any way to make it work without the 1 sec delay??

Comment: This is an environmental problem.  You have a very unusual and rather broken video driver.  Or whatever other utility messes with the mouse cursor appearance.

Comment: You're right! I don't have a regular cursor. I disabled it and now it works great. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Get cursor location, move to (0,0), take screenshot, put back cursor. The code works using APIs:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;

            public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
            {
                return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            POINT lpPoint;
            //Get current location of cursor
            GetCursorPos( out lpPoint );
            //Move to (0,0)
            SetCursorPos( 0, 0 );
            //Take screenshot
            //gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(//...);
            MessageBox.Show("just for create a delay", "Debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            //Put back cursor
            SetCursorPos( lpPoint.X, lpPoint.Y );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it didn't work either:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Point mouse_Temp = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(0, 0);  
         
   gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(//...);

   Cursor.Position = mouse_Temp;
}

Comment: I updated my answer with new code. The code works. I tested it. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks man. The code you wrote is more advanced than I can understand at the moment :P I'm a total beginner. It's ok I solved it. My code was not working because of a custom pointer that I have put on my mouse cursor.

Comment: Your welcome. Since you are new, I want to mention that if my code was helpful to you, it's nice to rate it. Good luck